# proof involving limit points

Tags: limits

Let E be a set of real numbers. If $x = \cdot \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n$ and if each $x_n$ is a limit point of E, show that x is also a limit point of E

I don't even know where to start. I don't think my professor ever explained limit points to us. If anyone can give me some insight on this type of problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that dot before the limit sign supposed to be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition, $\forall \epsilon$, $\exists N$ such that for $n > N$ we have $|x - x_n| < \epsilon/2$. Since each $x_n$ is a limit point of $E$, we know that in any neighborhood of $x_n$ there exists an $e \in E$ such that $|x_n - e| < \epsilon/2$. Consider $|x - e| = |x-x_n + x_n - e| \le |x - x_n| + |x_n - e| < \epsilon$. This implies that $e \in N_x(\epsilon)$, but $\epsilon$ was arbitrary and so $x$ is a limit point.

Comment: can you explain the conclusion of the proof... "but $\epsilon$ was arbitrary and so $x$ is a limit point". How does $\epsilon \in N_x(\epsilon) $ prove that $x$ is a limit point?

Comment: Apologies, it should have been $e$ not $\epsilon$. The fact that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary shows that we may find an element of $E$ in any neighborhood in $x$, but this is the definition of a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that E is a **sub**set of the set of all real numbers.  A point, p, is a limit point for a set E if and only if, given any number $\epsilon> 0$, there exist at least one **other point**, q, in E such that $d(p, q)< \epsilon$.